# how to get price information from a website?

Tags: excel, vba

I try to get the price information from a webpage and save it to an excel cell.[link](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPOV.asp?itemType=S&itemNo=8868&itemSeq=1&itemQty=1&breakType=M&itemCondition=N&incInstr=Y&incParts=Y) 
I have found the html parser and created the code below and another question on stackoverflow : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

```
Sub bee()

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim htmTable As HTMLTable

Set doc = New HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPOV.asp?itemType=S&itemNo=8868&itemSeq=1&itemQty=1&breakType=M&itemCondition=N&incInstr=Y&incParts=Y"
End With
```

although I do not understand and know how to proceed. can somebody help with this :S ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is many different ways to go to make that you want,

Here is one way you could go :)

```
Sub ParseTable()
Dim htm As Object: Set htm = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Dim tr As Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://pastebin.com/raw/BY51yHwd", False
        .send
        htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With


    For Each tr In htm.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        If Len(tr.ID) > 0 Then MsgBox tr.ID ' msgbox the table row
    Next tr
End Sub
```

You need to find out which table the content is in, I believe the table name is **"tb-main-content"**

Here is a link to the example table I made:
http://pastebin.com/raw/BY51yHwd

Have a nice day

Comment: hi thx for you comment. But on the website i need to do this the tables do not have any id's how should i do it then ?